# Are black holes stationary?

Tags: particle-physics, black-holes

If light/energy with zero mass hits the speed limit, are black holes with infinite density at a universal standstill with everything moving relative to them?

Am I barking up the wrong tree as they would move relative to each other?

Answer (score 1):

The fact they are blackholes dosen't really change how mass behaves in a classical perspective. For example, if the sun was somehow replaced by a blackhole of the same mass, nothing would change in the solar system in terms of gravitation. And this small blackhole would follow the same path as the sun around the Milkyway's core. It's also possible for two blackholes to orbit around eachother.

Comment: i see what your saying, but like light always travels at the same speed(not velocity) wether in a vacume or not a star would rotate(giving it speed) as would a black hole but the point or center of a blackhole has infinate density or no speed.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the fact that it has infinite density dosen't make the fact it moves impossible. Imagine a moving star collapsing into a black hole. It would make no sens that it suddenly stops.

Comment: mmmmmmmmmm. cheers